# Execute function via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

On my site I have a number of links to various external booking forms that should open in new windows. Unfortunately I can only change each links class (can't set the Id's).

What I'm trying to do is to come up with a Javascript that has a function for each external site to open in a new window. And some jQuery that executes the proper function for the link clicked with a certain class in it.

This is one of the functions (others have a different name and url):

```
    function booking-site-1(elt) {
    window.open("https://bookings.domainname.eu/4043/31", "_blank", "toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=745");
}
```

And this is the jQuery

```
jQuery(".booking-site-1-class").click(function(){
                       alert("Finally!")});
```

Where the jQuery now successfully shows the alert when I click a link I'd like it to execute the function shown above. I such a n00b that I don't know how to do that.

Hope that someone could give me a few pointers here.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, function names declared using `var/const/let/function` can't have hyphens `-` - in fact, no names declared as such in JavaScript can. Use underscores instead:

```
function booking_site_1(elt) {
    window.open("https://bookings.domainname.eu/4043/31", "_blank", "toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=745");
}
```

And to make it execute, just add it to your click handling function:

```
jQuery(".booking-site-1-class").click(function(){
    alert("Finally!");
    booking_site_1($("#randomElement"));
});
```

As pointed out by [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271011/execute-function-via-jquery/55271039#comment97274163_55271039), you can make functions as a property of the `window` object, or of any object,

Comment: Wow, thanks for the super quick reply!

I changed the function to underscores and changed the jQuery to this (the alert was just there as a proof of concept):

    
`jQuery(".booking-site-1-class").click(function(){
    booking_site_1(jQuery("#randomElement"));
});`

And it works! :-)

I'm wondering though what this is for #randomElement

Comment: Yes @Rob - the `#randomElement` was just as a demonstration of how you would use it. You can replace that with any element you wish.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I could take that out then?

Comment: Since you don't use the `elt` param in your function, yes, just execute it like `booking_site_1()`.

Comment: Thanks! Giving that a try now.

Comment: The script is all cleaned up now and fully functional. Just wondering about the 'elt' that I copied when I frankensteined the script together. I can't find any reference to this param, but when I delete it the script stops functioning. Is it necessary or did I just remove it incorrectly?

Comment: Just make sure it's like `function booking_site_1() { window.open("https://bookings.domainname.eu/4043/31", "_blank", "toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=745");
}`

Comment: to be perfectly accurate, a function declared like `window['this-is-a-function'] = function() { ... }` is possible :p - while var/let/const/function declarations are restricted in their name, object property names are not

Comment: Well yes @JaromandaX, but you would still have to call it as an object property `window["hyphen-function"](args)`

Comment: indeed you would, but saying function names can't have `-` in them is not strictly correct  - I have use cases where I rely on this lack of restriction, though, never on the global (window) object, usually as a property of some other object :p

Comment: don't make too much of it - because what you say is actually correct when declaring a `function xxx` ... `xxx` is restricted,